# Заменить значения ключей объектов другим значениями

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы, объекты

У меня есть два массива

```
let arr1 = [
    {
        category_id: '28',
        count: 16,
    },
    {
        category_id: '31',
        count: 8,
    },
];

let arr2 = [
    {
        id: '28',
        name: 'Общая',
    },
    {
        id: '31',
        name: 'Тестовая категория',
    },
];
```

и мне нужно вывести в новый массив данные, заменив значения ключа ***category_id*** первого массива, на значения, по совпадению цифр, ключа ***name*** второго массива.

В итоге должно быть что-то такое, либо со старым ключом ***category_id***

```
[
    {
        category: 'Общая',
        count: 16,
    },
    {
        category: 'Тестовая категория',
        count: 8,
    },
]
```

Comment: на данные ваши посмотрели, а код-то где? Преобразуйте второй массив к парам ключ-значение, и пройдитесь по первому с заменой

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю что вам могло показаться здесь сложного. Я написал небольшой алгоритм.

```
let arr1 = [
    {
        category_id: '28',
        count: 16,
    },
    {
        category_id: '31',
        count: 8,
    },
];

let arr2 = [
    {
        id: '28',
        name: 'Общая',
    },
    {
        id: '31',
        name: 'Тестовая категория',
    },
];
////Мой код
const categories= arr1.map((obj)=>{
    let category = arr2.find(cat=>cat['id']===obj['category_id'])['name']
    return {
        cound:obj.count,
        category
    }
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, что-то немного затупил. Теперь разобрался

Comment: "Не знаю что вам могло показаться здесь сложного" - именно по этой причине тут принято сначла дожидаться кода самого автора, чтобы быть уверенным что он пытался хоть что-то сделать  :)

Comment: Учту, спасибо за ваше наставление